# Why does a non-default last-case execute in JavaScript switch?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, break

I have (ab)used a `switch` statement like this:

```
const foo = figureOutWhatFooIs()
console.log(foo) // 'bar'

switch (foo) {
  case 'bar':
    console.log('foo = bar')
  case 'baz':
    console.log('foo = baz')
}
```

i.e. no `break`'s and no `default`

I discovered that even when `foo = 'bar'`, the `baz` case (and incidentally the last case) also executes.

I'm not surprised that the last case was *checked* but I am surprised that it executed.  Thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: Because there are no `break`s.

Comment: That's... how `break` works...

Comment: yea but `case 'baz'` should not _match_ - why is a case that did not match get executed?

Comment: _Because there are no `break`s._ Read e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch - _"executes statements after the first `case` clause with a matching value, until a `break` statement is encountered"_.

Comment: ahhhh ok executes statements (PLURAL) after a match - amazing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking is done at the start of `switch` statement, not *during* running `case` statements.

The `case` clause works similar to labels and `goto`/`JUMP` statements in other languages such as C++<sup>1</sup> and Assembly<sup>2</sup>, which means `case 'bar':` is nothing more than a label that can be used to *jump* execution to it, but does nothing logical in itself.

So, when a `case` clause matches, JavaScript *jumps* you to that label, and then runs all statements one by one, ignoring any other `case` clauses because they're simply labels.

But of course, if there's any `break` statement along the way, it'll exit `switch`.

The main reason switch statement does not break by default could be so that it's easier to match multiple conditions like this:

```
switch (color) {
  case 'red':
  case 'orange':
  case 'blue':
    console.log('Colorful!');
    break;
  case 'black':
  case 'white':
  case 'gray':
    console.log('Black & white!');
    break;
  default:
    console.log('What color is that??');
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto

<sup>2</sup> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_conditions.htm

Answer (score 2):

it is because you are not using break, so after running the first case, is going to continue with the others. Make a test, adding another 2 cases, one before 'bar' case and the second after it. The first one isn't going to run when foo = 'bar' (because is before) but the second is going to run, and if you add more cases after the 'bar' case, every one is going to execute if you don't use break. That's why is very important to use in switch